# Generate duplicate rows in Oracle based on id

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate rows based on below conditions . As per below example User A having documents Doc1 and Doc2 with **id =1** . For the user name **B** ,**id=2** which is greater than **id=1** so I want to generate all the document Names for the user name **B** which user name **A** having along with what already he have. Same rule follows for user name **C**

[image: Input]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would self-join do?

For sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id, user_name, document_name;

        ID DOCUMENT_NAME   USER_NAME  COUNTRY
---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
         1 Doc1            A          US
         1 Doc2            A          US
         2 Doc3            B          CA
         3 Doc4            C          CA
```

Query & result:

```
SQL> select distinct a.id, b.document_name, a.user_name, a.country
  2  from test a join test b on b.id <= a.id
  3  order by id, user_name, document_name;

        ID DOCUMENT_NAME   USER_NAME  COUNTRY
---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
         1 Doc1            A          US
         1 Doc2            A          US
         2 Doc1            B          CA
         2 Doc2            B          CA
         2 Doc3            B          CA
         3 Doc1            C          CA
         3 Doc2            C          CA
         3 Doc3            C          CA
         3 Doc4            C          CA

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT t2.id,
         t1.document_name,
         t2.user_name,
         t2.country
  FROM   table_name t1
         INNER JOIN table_name t2
         ON (t1.id < t2.id )
) src
ON (    src.id            = dst.id
    AND src.document_name = dst.document_name
    AND src.user_name     = dst.user_name
    AND src.country       = dst.country )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, document_name, user_name, country)
  VALUES (src.id, src.document_name, src.user_name, src.country);
```

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, document_name, user_name, country) AS
SELECT 1, 'Doc1', 'A', 'US' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Doc2', 'A', 'US' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Doc3', 'B', 'CA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Doc4', 'B', 'CA' FROM DUAL;
```

After the `MERGE`, the table contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

> | ID | DOCUMENT_NAME | USER_NAME | COUNTRY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Doc1 | A | US |
> | 1 | Doc2 | A | US |
> | 2 | Doc3 | B | CA |
> | 3 | Doc4 | B | CA |
> | 2 | Doc1 | B | CA |
> | 2 | Doc2 | B | CA |
> | 3 | Doc1 | B | CA |
> | 3 | Doc3 | B | CA |
> | 3 | Doc2 | B | CA |

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3a34/1)*